# Fetch all the branches in git and get Hashcode for all the branches

Tags: git

I am trying to get a command in git which can help me fetch list of all the branches or my code and also list down all the hashcode in front of same . As I want to delete all my stale branches and keep it safe for later retrieval.

To List all the branches following command is enough.

```
Git branch -r
```

to get the hashcode for a branch

```
git rev-parse <BranchName>
```

can I get one command where it list all branches and hashcode in front of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 git for-each-ref refs/remotes --format="%(objectname) %(refname:lstrip=2)"
```

`git for-each-ref` outputs information on all local refs.

`refs/remotes` is the pattern for remote tracking branches. Only the refs matching the pattern will be printed.

`--format` formats the output. Here `%(objectname)` refers to the commit hash. A following space is literally a space. `%(refname)` refers to the ref name. The full name of a remote tracking branch is like  `refs/remotes/origin/foo`. `:lstrip=2` suppresses the left 2 parts `refs` and `remotes`.

See [git for-each-ref](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref) for more.

Answer (score 1):

I used `cut` and `while` loops to reach to the solution:

```
git branch -r -l | cut -d " " -f 3 | while read i; do echo "$i: $(git rev-parse $i)"; done
```

Comment: works  fine , thanks , but one mentioned  above works perfectly and much faster .                                   
 git for-each-ref refs/remotes --format="%(objectname) %(refname:lstrip=2)"

Answer (score 0):

I got bit of answer  but still not the concrete on:

Commands used :
To List all branches :

```
git branch -r >>branchesList
```

List all Hashcode for branches :

```
for remote in git branch -r; do git rev-parse $remote ; done >> hascodeforbranches.txt*
```

Put it in an xl and u will have a mapping .